# How to find the given image source (url) is in svg format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am getting images as URLs from my CMS provider like this

**SVG image src URL:**

```
https://example.com/svg.png
```

Here I am getting images in different formats like png, jpeg, jpg, SVG, etc... In this, I need to find the images only in SVG format.

I planned to create a utility function and going to pass all the image URLs to it. It will return true only if the image is in SVG format else it will return false.

Is there any way I can do this in Javascript (ReactJS)? If any source or plugin is available. Please share that.

**Will this function work ?**

```
function isSvgFormatImage(url) {
  return url.split('.').includes('svg')
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is my solution works ? i have added one

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer to the question :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your function would work, one a little more efficient would be:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} url
 */
function isSVGFormatImage(url) {
  return url.endsWith(".svg");
}

// Some test cases

console.assert(isSVGFormatImage("https://example.com/another.svg") === true);

console.assert(isSVGFormatImage("https://example.com/svg.png") === false);

console.assert(isSVGFormatImage("https://example.com/file.jpg") === false);
```

- [console.assert docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/assert)

Answer (score 0):

If the url ends in ".svg", this function returns true

```
function isSvgFormat (url){
   return url.endsWith(".svg")
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I put three minutes before you :)